# How to send "%" in pyramid Response

Tags: python-2.7, pyramid

In pyramid i am doing

```
return Response(html % data)
```

where data is a dict with value for %(key)s in html.
it works fine.But when there is "%" in html it breaks .
So how do i fix that??

Comment: The escape sequence for a `%` in printf-style string formatting is `%%`.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of reinventing bicycles you need to use a proper templating library, Pyramid has addons for Chameleon, Jinja2 and Mako. Here's a [chapter on templates in Pyramid documentation](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/templates.html).

Apart from the obvious fragility, your approach is also a recipe for creating XSS vulnerabilities unless you manually escape all data.